# Xamarin.forms get/set viewcell properties in ContentPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, get, set

Can someone help me with some code on how to access properties in a viewcell from a ContentPage?   Specifically I have a label that pops up a DisplayActionsheet that I need to a) pass values to dynamically and b) grab values from when the user selects a choice.

I'm using C# versus XAML.  Thank you